# Regex to find only limited values before string

Tags: python, regex

Here is my text code

```
string = "Johnson \
          Age 20 \
          Hired"
```

I want to get Age 20. I did

```
value = re.match("^(.*?)Hired",string).group(1)
```

But that gets me Johnson and Age 20. I just want Age 20. Is there a way to limit what it is grabbing? The thing is name can change, it can be peter age something. So i cannot do between two strings because the first one is unknown, but "Hired" is known and will be present no matter what.

EDIT: Sorry I should have clarified, the "AGE" variable can change. It is a feature, so it could

```
Johnson \
salary 1000 \
Hired"
```

All i know is "Hired" will be there, and name of person can be different

Comment: I would suggest `"^.* Age (\d+) "`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you may try:

```
string = "Johnson \
          Age 20 \
          Hired"
          
import re

string = re.sub(r".+\b([A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+).+",r"\1",string)

print (string)
```

This will perfectly work if, as in your exemple, you have one user data in your string. To make with with more, juste make a list of string and loop through.

Using that regex will catch all "WoRd 1234" type of expressions.

At the OP request, to basically catch the before last line regardless the rest:

```
string = [item for item in string.split("  ") if item][-2]
```

Comment: Can you please check the edited post. I cannot use Age as that feature might change

Comment: My edit will work for each WORD NUMBER expression in your data

Comment: can you check your output? I am not getting AGe

Comment: That is fixed, sorry

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that you are assuming here that the feature can be a number. What if its, race asian, and thats the second line. The constant pattern is, some random name, feature and its value, and "Hired". What changes is name, and the feature value

Comment: Well, then replace ([A-Za-z]+ [0-9]+) by ([A-Za-z]+ [A-Za-z0-9]+). It will match every key value pair with key a word and value word or number or both

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227174/discussion-between-user3491702-and-synthase).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a word followed by a space followed by a number.  In a regex that'd be:

```
>>> re.findall("\S+ \d+", string)
['Age 20']
```

Note that if you get a name like "John Johnson the 3rd" this will not necessarily be so straightforward (although in that case you could simply take the *last* match and it'd still be fine).

Alternatively, if you just want to get the third and second from last words in the string, use `split` and `join`:

```
>>> " ".join(string.split()[-3:-1])
'Age 20'
```

If you can't assume that the string ends in `Hired`, just strip out everything after `Hired` up front:

```
>>> " ".join(string[:string.index("Hired")].rstrip().split()[-2:])
'Age 20'
```

Comment: Also the assumption is not entirely true. It is not always word followed by number, the feature can be something other than number. The constant pattern is, some random name, feature and its value, and "Hired". What changes is name, and the feature value

Comment: Seems like the parameters of this question change every five minutes.  Is it safe to assume that the variable name and value won't contain whitespace?  Does "Hired" always come at the end of the string, or can there be other junk after it?

Comment: This is neat, "" ".join(string.split()[-3:-1])", but what if feature is Null, which it can be. In case of null, there is nothing next to feature, so in that case, it will grab something from name as well.

Comment: I am sorry I should have slowed down and formulated the question properly before posting. My apologies

Comment: Hired is always at the end. The number of lines can change. We just need the line before Hired, which can contain one or more than one value.